# How to block login before User.accepted = 1?

Tags: authentication, cakephp

What would be best practice to block login when User is not yet accepted? In other words for example when User.accepted = 0.

I'm using CakePHP's Auth-component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a ["userScope" property](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1268/userScope) to your Auth component. I believe this should work for you:

```
 $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.accepted' => true);
```

Add that in your app controllers `beforeFilter()`.

Comment: Thanks! So far this is just what I'm looking for. Do you know if it is possible to view different error message than `$this->Auth->loginError`?

Comment: I saw this article in the bakery: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/m3nt0r/2008/09/21/authed-adds-rule-based-userscope-to-auth